# How to load file and run swift code from Swift Package Manager manifest file?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have and iOS Project that has a SPM dependency and I am trying to update the Package object inside the SPM manifest file(Package.swift) based on a configuration file to get something similar to:

```
// Package.swift
// swift-tools-version:5.3
import PackageDescription
import Foundation

var modules : [Modules] = getConfigurationFrom("file.json")

// Where getConfigurationFrom function calls to:
// Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file", ofType: "json")

if modules.first.isEnabled {
    // Build Package object with moduleA dependencies
    Package(name: "Package", ... Dependencies for ModuleA ...)
} else {
    // Build Package object with moduleB dependencies
    Package(name: "Package", ... Dependencies for ModuleB ...)
}
```

But I am not able to properly load the json file from the Main bundle, maybe am I missing something here? Or is there another way to build different dependencies based on a file using SPM without using party libraries?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using swift 5.3 and package resources? If so, and you are trying to load a file from the package you will need to update your bundle reference. `Bundle.module` will automatically be provided. `Bundle.main` will not include the resources from the package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @richardpiazza, yep I am using swift 5.3 I updated the question to provide a more clear example of what I am trying to accomplish here. I did try to use Bundle.module but is not available inside the manifest file although I can include Foundation and use other functions and structs that are defined in the same file. I think that I am not able to use Bundle.module since this is the step before the actual compilation of the modules in Package(...) object

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to achieve what you've intended. You may need to wait for the rest of [Conditional Target Dependences](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0273-swiftpm-conditional-target-dependencies.md) to be implemented before something similar becomes available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit hacky, but you can get path to current file using `#file`, so if you are interested in file.json that is placed in the same directory as Package.swift, you can do this:

```swift
let packageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: #file).deletingLastPathComponent()
let fileURL = packageURL.appendingPathComponent("file.json")
```

Comment: This is a great way (only way, I believe) solution to get the file from outside of the bundle, for scenarios where you don't want to include the file(s) within the app Bundle.